# Name for $X^\infty=\bigcup\limits_{k=0}^\infty X^k$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I'm making structures associated with groups, rings and so on in OCaml and in order to do so I started by defining sets and a few operations (intersection, union, difference, carthesian product, carthesian power) and now I want to define a set $X^\infty=\bigcup\limits_{k=0}^\infty X^k\subsetneq X^\Bbb N$ which I would represent with arrays but I couldn't find a proper name for it. Is there one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the free monoid on the set $X$. A monoid is a set together with a binary operation which is associative and has a unit. The monoid structure on the set you call $X^{\infty }$ is concatenation and the unit is the unique $0$-tuple (the only element in the set $X^0$). The more common notation for the free monoid is $X^*$.

Answer (score 1):

This is the set of finite sequences from $X$. It has many notations, for example $X^\ast, X^{<\Bbb N}, X^{<\omega}$.

It is easy to note that this is also equivalent to the set of [formal] polynomials over $X$.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the infinite disjoint union, you could call it the *coproduct* of the sets $X_k$. If they are not disjoint, you could call it the *coequalizer* of the $X_k$ (note: both are category theoretical notions, and generalize to every category, not only the category $\mathbf{Sets}$ of sets and arbitrary maps of sets).

Comment: $X^k$ is the sequences of length $k$, not some set $X_k$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah, sorry, it wasn't clear to me from the statement of the question.